# I wrote a jquery 'lightbox' style function,but am struggling to create seamless loop of images in lightbox left/right

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-gallery

I wrote some script to give my gallery a lightbox style gallery, and I want to be able to go through it with the left and right chevrons I added, so I added the function to do this. But while my left function loops through the gallery to the start and then to the end to give the image of a seamless loop, my right function doesn't work, it goes directly to the final image and then will not continue. Can anyone suggest why this is? What am I doing wrong here,

```
  var currentImage;

  $(document).ready(function() {


  $('.lightboxBG').hide();

  });


  $(document).ready(function(){


  $('.galleryphoto').click(function()
  {
  var image_href = $(this).attr("src");


  $('.lightboxBG').show();
  $('.lightboxIMG').attr("src",image_href);

  currentImage = image_href;


  });

  var images = $("img.galleryphoto").map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src");
  });



  var left = $('.fa-chevron-left');
  var right = $('.fa-chevron-right');

  //here is the function which doesn't want to work.
  right.click(function(){

   for(var j = 0; j < images.length; j++){
   if(images[j]=== currentImage){

      if(images[j+1] !== undefined){


      $('.lightboxIMG').attr("src", images[j+1]);
      currentImage = images[j+1];
      }
      else{$('.lightboxIMG').attr("src", images[0]);

  currentImage = images[0];

  }
     }
   }    
  });

    // here is the function which works nicely.
  left.click(function(){

   for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){

     if(images[i]=== currentImage){


      if(images[i-1] !== undefined){
          $('.lightboxIMG').attr("src", images[i-1]);
      currentImage = images[i-1];
      }
       else{$('.lightboxIMG').attr("src", images[images.length-1])
          currentImage = images[images.length-1];
   }
     }
   }    
  });



  $('.fa-window-close').click(function(){

  $('.lightboxBG').hide();

  })



  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would advice you to use something like vs code so you could post properly aligned code, this mess is really hard to read.

The following should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentIndex;
  const imageUrls = Array.from(
    $("img.galleryphoto").map(function() {
      return $(this).attr("src");
    })
  ),
  next = function(direction){
    currentIndex = currentIndex + direction;
    if(currentIndex>=imageUrls.length){
      currentIndex = 0;
    }
    if(currentIndex<0){
      currentIndex = imageUrls.length-1;
    }
    $('.lightboxIMG').attr("src", imageUrls[currentIndex]);
  };

  $('.lightboxBG').hide();
  //changed this to img.galleryphoto so it's the same as imageUrls
  $('img.galleryphoto').click(function(){
    currentIndex = imageUrls.indexOf($(this).attr("src"));
    $('.lightboxBG').show();
    $('.lightboxIMG').attr("src",imageUrls[currentIndex]);
  });
  //here is the function which doesn't want to work.
  $('.fa-chevron-right').click(function(){
    next(1);
  });

  // here is the function which works nicely.
  $('.fa-chevron-left').click(function(){
    next(-1);
  });

  $('.fa-window-close').click(function(){    
    $('.lightboxBG').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that , sorry about the code, I am going to examine yours thoroughly and try to rewrite it so I can do it in the future, I have also taken your advice and downloaded vs code, I was using sublime before and I always struggle to format it for stackoverflow. I know you've been helpful anyway but did you see any reason why my code wasn't working, I can tell yours is much more clear and to the point, but I get really fixed on why a piece of code fails, like what was I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry I also im getting a typeError on your code thrown which says .indexOf is not a function

Comment: If you're interested, this didn't work because ````const imageUrls = $("img.galleryphoto").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("src");````    was creating an object, and indexOf needed an array to work, so i used  ````var imageUrls = Array();

$('img.galleryphoto').each(function(){
     imageUrls.push($(this).attr('src'));
});````  and now we are working ;)

Comment: @JamesVitaly Updated the answer, jQuery.map returns an object that is not an array so added `Array.from` you already figured that one out though.

Comment: @JamesVitaly to answer your question about what's wrong with your original code: in `right.click` after setting source and set the value for `currentImage` in the for loop do a `break;`, you've set the image and there is no need to continue the loop. If you do so then every time `images[j]=== currentImage` is true